# Character array insertion in postgresql using Npgsql

Tags: c#, arrays, postgresql, npgsql

I would like to insert an array of strings into a table in PostgreSQL using Npgsql in C#. I have written the code below but am getting an InvalidCastexception.

```
eventcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@participants", NpgsqlDbType.Array).Value = participant.Text;
```

where participant is an textbox and eventcommand is an NpgsqlCommand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `AddWithValue`, but not providing the value - you're providing the *type*. Additionally, you're not providing an array - you're just providing a single string. I suspect you just want:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@participants", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Text).Value
    = new[] { participant.Text };
```

Or you may want to split `participant.Text` into an array of strings first, or something similar.

(I've adjusted the type as per comments.)

Comment: Note also that NpgsqlDbType.Array needs to be bitwise ORed with the element type, so NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Text for array of strings

Comment: @Shay: Thanks, fixed.