# Can you convert C# byte[] to postgressql bytea using Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

So I am having a problem casting a `byte[]` to a `bytea` in postgres. I have a program that takes in a password(string) that in converted to byte[] using HMACSHA512. I want to insert my `byte[]` data into my postgres database.

Insert Statement

```
public static int Insert(User user)
    {
      string sqlcommand = $"INSERT INTO \"{Settings.UserTable}\" (userName, surname, email, passwordhash, passwordsalt, status) VALUES (@name, @surname, @email, encode(E'@passwordhash'::bytea, 'escape'), @passwordsalt::bytea, 0::bit)";
      using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlcommand, DatabaseConnection.Connection))
      {

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", user.Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("surname", user.Surname);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", user.Email);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("passwordhash", user.PasswordHash);

        int result = (int)command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return result;
      }
    }
```

Model

```
    public class User
    {
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        
        public int status { get; set; }

        public string Token { get; set; }
        public DateTime TokenCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime TokenExpires { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            
        }

        public User(string name, string surname, string email, byte[] passwordHash, byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Surname = surname;
            this.Email = email;
            this.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            this.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
        }
```

And here is my controller

```
[HttpPost("Register")]
        public IActionResult Register([FromBody] Register model)
        {
            var user = new User { Name = model.Name, Surname = model.Surname, Email = model.Email};


            using (HMACSHA512? hmac = new HMACSHA512())
            {
                user.PasswordSalt = hmac.Key;
                user.PasswordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(model.Password));
            }

            UserQuery.Insert(user);

            return Ok(user);
        }
```

My problem is that it keeps giving me this error

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Parameter 'name' must have either its NpgsqlDbType or its DataTypeName or its Value set
```

And I'm assuming it's something to do with the casting of the passwordHash and passwordSalt

Comment: have you looked at the `NpgsqlDbType` type you could set the type of the column before setting it according to the exception you have provided. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31891374/18278998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error indicates that that the `@name` parameter is null, and so Npgsql doesn't know which type to send. If the intention really is to insert null names, then you can set NpgsqlDbType on NpgsqlParameter.

Note that the following won't work: `encode(E'@passwordhash'::bytea, 'escape')`; you can't put a parameter placeholder inside a string in this way. If `@passwordhash` is a `byte[]` in .NET and you wish to pass it to PG `encode`, simply do `encode(@passwordhash, 'escape')`.